# For Loop alternative with Lodash ( React Native )

Tags: arrays, react-native, sorting, lodash

I was trying to itertate an array and access description

Array
[image]

i'm itertaing via regular for loop like this

```
 for (var index = 0; index <components.length; index++) {
    const msgs  = components[index].messages;
    for(var value = 0; value < msgs.length; value ++ ){
      console.log(msgs[value].description);
    }
  }
```

Please let me know how we can simplify it by using loadash methods in react native.

Answer (score 0):

here it is using lodash

```
import {forEach} from 'lodash';


forEach(components,(component,index)=>{
  const msgs  = component.messages;
  forEach(msgs,(msg,value)=>{
    console.log(msg.description);
  });
});
```